# What are hadron parity partners?

Tags: definition, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, parity, hadron-dynamics

I am studying Lattice QCD and there are many papers mentioning "Parity partners". What does this term mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think people are usually referring to parity partners of hadrons and not of quarks as your title might suggest. The parity partner of the positive parity nucleon is for example the negative parity N(1535) (see for example [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-N-1535-1o2-minus.pdf)). Parity partner in this context refers to two hadrons which have identical quantum numbers except for parity.